# Selenium Python Export Power BI report as Export Data as excel file

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, powerbi

Using Selenium and Python I was able to fill-in the form and generate the report. Power BI report displaying in `iframe`.  Now I am trying to export the report in excel format.

Looking some guidance to complete the last three steps to export the report.

This code moves to the table and popup the three menu options. unsure how to click the three `...` from the popup.

```
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth", block: "end"})', element)
time.sleep(2)
webdriver.ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element).perform()
```

1. Report displayed in table format, when I move the mouse to the table, it displays three options in the right side top the table. I need to click `three dots` option.

[image]

2. When I click the three-dot option, its popup the another menu. In this menu I need to click `Export data` option.
   [image]
3. When I click the export data option, it will open another popup in this I need to click `Export` button.
   [image]

Any tips to automate this steps will be help full.

Comment: Any chance you could publish the HTML of the page?

Comment: @ZachBellay my report is internal, I can see this report close to my use case https://excellab.at/kununu-bewertungen/ from this frame, if we can click `Focus mode` option in the right hand side top. that will help me.

Answer (score 0):

Used the below function to find the element in the recursive `iframe`.  in this second iframe has the `more option`. same kind of function used to find other two elements also.

```
def find_more_option(driver):
    action = "more option"
    print(f"======== Looking for {action} link =======")
    iframes = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//iframe")
    for index, iframe in enumerate(iframes):
        print("=========== src attribute")
        iframe_url = iframe.get_attribute("src")
        print(f"iframe url {iframe_url}")
        driver.switch_to.frame(index)
        try:
            element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[@class="vcMenuBtn"]')
            if element:
                print(f"found the element for - {action}")
                WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(element)).click()
                break

        except NoSuchElementException as e:
            print(f"unable to find the {action}: " + repr(e))

        find_more_option(driver)
        driver.switch_to.parent_frame()
```